# Rails each loop to find condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using an API that gives me an array of objects, say `Users`. Each `user` has an attribute, `date`. I'm trying to find the number of `users` with a certain condition, say `where(date < Date.today)`.

Unfortunately, when I try calling `users.where('date < ?', Date.today).size` I get the error

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007f974ac2cfc0>
```

I assume it's because `where` is used for database queries. So I assume I need to iterate over each object and find the ones that match the condition. Something like

```
users.each { |user| user.date < Date.today }.size
```

But this just returns the total count of all the `users`. So I assume something in the `.each` block is wrong. Can someone please shed some light to this please? Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.each` is an iterator, not a "selector" as you need. Use `Array#select`:

```
users.select { |user| user.date < Date.today }.size
```

If you really want to use `.each`, you can do like this:

```
anterior_users = []
users.each { |user| anterior_users << user if user.date < Date.today }
anterior_users.size
```